# how to send to multiple recipients

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email to multiple recipients using the below email,but it only sends to the first email,any idea why and how to send to multiple recipients?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP

def email (body,subject,SendToList):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body, 'html')
    msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=UTF8"
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    s = SMTP('localhost',25)
    s.sendmail('fromuserid@company.com', SendToList,msg=msg.as_string())

def main ():
    SendToList = 'userid1@company.com,userid2@company.com'
    with open('email.txt', 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()
    subject = "test email"
    email(body,subject,SendToList)
    print "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail):

> SMTP.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg[, mail_options, rcpt_options])
>
> Send mail. The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string,
>   **a list of RFC 822 to-address strings** (a bare string will be treated as
>   a list with 1 address), and a message string.

So you need to send it a list:

```
def main ():
    send_to_list = ['userid1@company.com','userid2@company.com']
```